# How to append newline to text value in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, whitespace, carriage-return

I have a narrow button that contains an image and label text. The state of the button changes to one of several values which are stored as text in an array and then changed out with **textContent**.

[image]

One of the values forces a line break in the label text. I would like to reserve the "blank line" below my label so that layout isn't affected every time the label breaks to two lines of text. To accomplish this, I'm trying to append a newline to every single-line value. For layout reasons, I can't simply pad the container — I need it to match the height of a line of formatted text.

Is there any way to put a newline into a text array value? I've tried adding a CR to my text both within the array and prior to the array as a variable using:

```
Labelname + \n
Labelname\n&nbsp;
Labelname<br /> (HTML, I know)
var label = 'Labelname' + String.fromCharCode(13)
```

Nothing seems to make the newline "stick," and the console reveals the value "Labelname" without the newline.

Comment: Using a [flex layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is one way to achieve equal-height elements without messing around with their content

Comment: You've to wrap the newline in the quotes: `Labelname + '\n'` when you want to add a newline to the console. When adding it to HTML, you need HTML, `textContent` is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

HTML generally ignores whitespace (including newline characters). To have it rendered, you need to use an element that *doesn't* ignore whitespace (like `<pre>`), or opt in to `<pre>`-style whitespace handling via CSS with [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using **innerHTML** to put formatted text into the element. I was resistant to using it [for various reasons](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-disadvantage-of-using-innerhtml-in-javascript/), but it provided a straightforward solution to this problem.